# Unable to install add-ons (extensions) in Thunderbird 60 (Ubuntu 18.04) and 68.2.2 (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: software-installation, email, thunderbird, add-on

For some months I can **not directly install** a lot of **add-ons** within **Thunderbird** (Version 60.8.0, Ubuntu 18.04 and now also with 68.2.2, Ubuntu 19.10), some add-ons can be directly installed, especially the featured ones. The download button would be greyed out although the add-on "works with Thunderbird 57.* - 68.*". For **example**: [ReplyWithHeader](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/replywithheader/)
If I download the add-on as xpi-file and **install it manually. It works just fine.**
Some possible **[explanations on Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/unable-install-add-on-extension-theme-thunderbird) seem not to fit** (or do they?).
Is this a problem because of the Ubuntu version of Thunderbird or is it a problem with the add-on? Or does anybody have an another **hint**?